# Why is Horizontal Scrolling is not working when a List View is placed inside a horizontal ScrollView?

Tags: android, listview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have a simple list view which is placed inside a Horizontal Scroll view so that I can scroll horizontally when the list view content is too long.  When I place Text View inside the horizontalScrollView, I could scroll horizontally.  But, with list view it doesn't work.
Any body had the same issue?  Any work around for this?

```
 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/newListBoxContainerHSV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#FF00FF">
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFF00"
                    >
                </ListView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `ListView` is not meant to be put inside any `ScrollView`. It's considered a **bad practice**, as `ListView` itself has a built-in `ScrollView` and you may use it, so try avoiding at any price a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`.

If necessary, redesign your layout to not need it, as it goes against Android's design.

Comment: just to add to this, if you want to do horizontal scrolling you should look at using a `ViewPager` then you can put a listview in that

Comment: The documentation for ScrollView tells us not to use ListView inside ScrollView.  But, i am referring to HorizontalScrollView.